# Continue to record with MediaRecorder after page refresh

Tags: javascript, recording

I'm recording a stream from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` (laptop camera and headset microphone) using `MediaRecorder`. Let's imagine that I refresh the browser page while recording. Question: is there any way to continue recording to the same file that was being recorded before the refresh?

Comment: Well, not in the browser because that data is lost. Might be possible if you'd stream the recorded data directly to a server.

Comment: Thank you, @EmielZuurbier. I'm disappointed))